# Nginx not updating JS file changes

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, nginx, server

My server seems to be serving an old js file and ignoring recent changes. This is happening with a simple app.js file with one express route.

It's not client side caching from what I can tell (incognito and forced refresh hasn't worked)and nor has adding `sendfile off` to the location block. I also can't find the nginx cache folder to delete that some suggest

Restarting nginx doesn't help, but turning the digital ocean server off then on *does* fix the problem. Was hoping that info might help someone spot the problem I'm having?

** Edit

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     1    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 12 May 2020 01:35:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1
X-Powered-By: Express
ETag: W/"1-5p8g6faDkg0/tDKavZUeh4sfk3I"
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: could you update your question with output of `$ curl -I https://example.com/your-page`?

Comment: Is the JS file served by express or nginx? It may be Express that is not sending the updated file.

Comment: Ah, could it be that I'm using PM2 and therefore it isn't watching for changes? I'm not sure why restarting nginx doesn't fix this though.

Comment: Could be worth trying `curl` against the Express server ip/port (bypassing Nginx entirely) and see if it changes there

Comment: Ugh, I was an idiot and didn't have pm2 run the app using the --watch flag. Thanks for your help though!